# Find the smallest $4$ digit number which is a factor of $2005^6 - 1$.

Tags: factoring

Find the smallest $4$ digit number which is a factor of $2005^6 - 1$.

*My attempt*:

We see that $(2005-1)$ is a factor of $2005^6-1$ by the factorization of $2005^6-1$. Therefore, $1002$ is a factor of $2005^6-1$. I then have to show that $1001$ is not a factor but how do I do that? Should I use the factorization of $x^6-1$?

Comment: $2005^6-1\equiv 3^6-1\not \equiv 0 \pmod {1001}$.

Comment: @Macavity You ought to make that an answer. (Also, technically $1000$ has to be eliminated but that's nearly trivial.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$2005^6-1\equiv 3^6-1\not \equiv 0 \pmod {1001}$. Further, as mentioned in comments by Steven, you need to eliminate $1000$ as a factor too.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try basic algebra to figure this out:

$$ (2,005^6 = 64,966,020,037,537,515,625) - 1 = 64,966,020,037,537,515,624 $$

We already know that this number isn't divisible by $1,000$, so what about the others?

$$ \frac{2,005^6 - 1}{1,001} = 64,901,118,918,618,896.72 $$
$$ \frac{2,005^6 - 1}{1,002} = 64,836,347,342,851,812 $$

The real answer to this is $1,002$ then.